# Accessing SerialPort from Android Phone with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, serial-port, usbserial

I have developed a React Native app for Android device to connect with a HW board and one of the functionality is to communicate with HW board with Serial I/F Adapter from Mobile .

I have tried out multiple npm packages and none of them I could get to work.

Here is my sample code

```
import SerialPortAPI from 'react-native-serial-port-api';

    const path = await SerialPortAPI.devicePaths(paths => {
      console.log("List paths", paths)
    })


  const connectDevice = async (cfg) => {
    const { baudRate, serialPortName, stopBits } = cfg
    serialPort = await SerialPortAPI.open(serialPortName, { baudRate, stopBits});

    const sub = serialPort.onReceived(buff => {
      const str = buff.toString('hex').toUpperCase()
      console.log(str);
    })
    await serialPort.send('A7B7');
  }
```

It is NOT listing the device List connected and also not able to open/write/read.
Other packages I tried are:

1. react-native-usbserial
2. react-native-serialport
3. react-native-usb-serialport
4. react-native-serial-port-api

I any pointers and working sample will be of great help.
Regards
Raghu VT

Comment: Did you try connecting to the HW board using some serial terminal app to test if it is even able to connect to Android? Also, were you ever able to solve the problem and get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting the phone to your pc or it should work as host? I think that is key point to understand.

My phone is Host and I started with Android code.

Would recommend to use Android to test if possible.

You want to pay attention to the port type used.

If you use a USB AB connector you need to use an otg cable or adapter.

if case of type C , this will be detected automatically.

Hope could provide some hints

Comment: The Phone will NOT be connected to PC. It will be connected directly to HW Board with USB cable ( thru Adapter Card)

Comment: is the adapter card chip supported by the driver ? I am using for example CP210x chip